# Why isn't my systemd timer executing my sh script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, arch-linux, systemd, systemd-timer

My `youtube.sh` file located in `/home/deck/Desktop/youtube.sh`:

```
#1/bin/env bash
pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 100%
xdg-open A youtube video link
```

My `youtube.timer` file located in `/etc/systemd/system/youtube.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Youtube Timer

[Timer]
Unit=youtube.service
OnCalendar=*-*-* 10:40:00
Persistent=True
[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

My `youtube.service` file located in `/etc/systemd/system/youtube.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Youtube Service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/deck/Desktop/youtube.sh
```

When I run `systemctl status youtube.timer` in the terminal I get:

```
(1)(deck@steamdeck ~)$ sudo systemctl status youtube.timer
[sudo] password for deck: 
● youtube.timer - My Youtube Timer
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/youtube.timer; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Thu 2023-03-09 10:34:54 EST; 31min ago
      Until: Thu 2023-03-09 10:34:54 EST; 31min ago
    Trigger: Fri 2023-03-10 10:40:00 EST; 23h left
   Triggers: ● youtube.service

Mar 09 10:34:54 steamdeck systemd[1]: Started My Youtube Timer.
(deck@steamdeck ~)$
```

It says it ran but at 10:40am the youtube video did not open in my browser I am really bad with code so please go easy on me is there a simpler way to do this? also why didn't it execute

---

Alright I moved the youtube.service and youtube.timer to `/home/deck/.config/systemd/user/` as instructed and tried running the following commands in the terminal:

```
(deck@steamdeck system)$ systemctl --user daemon-reload
(deck@steamdeck system)$ systemctl --user enable youtube.timer
(deck@steamdeck system)$ systemctl --user status youtube.timer
○ youtube.timer - My Youtube Timer
     Loaded: loaded (/home/deck/.config/systemd/user/youtube.timer; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
    Trigger: n/a
   Triggers: ● youtube.service
```

Now apparently the trigger is n/a and its inactive i tried enabling it I used `systemctl --user daemon-reload` so why isn't it recognizing it?

Comment: can you elaborate more what can i change that to make it work? is it the extra space? what is the correct way to type it?

Comment: `#!/bin/env bash`

Comment: Re: your edit... you have to `systemctl --user start youtube.timer`.  `enable` only makes it active on boots.  `start` makes it active now.   Also, before you play with the timer, make sure the service works by using `systemctl --user start youtube.service`.  Once you are confident that works, then integrate it with the timer.

Comment: Are you pranking someone?  This looks like a fun-way to rick-roll someone.

Answer (score 2):

As Vlastimil Burián and PonJar already commented, your script's first line has a typo:

```
#1/bin/env bash
```

should be:

```
#!/bin/env bash
```

But there's also a deeper issue.

You have defined your `youtube.service` as a *system service*, so it runs as root by default. But you aren't logged in to the GUI as root, are you? And even if you were, the system services don't get to intrude on a GUI session by default.

You would have to set up at least the `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` environment variables properly to gain access to the GUI from a system service, and the right way to set `XAUTHORITY` depends on the X display manager you're running (`gdm`, `sddm`, `xdm` or `<something-else>dm`), and whether there is currently a logged-in GUI session or not.

So, first, the `pactl` command will fail because PulseAudio will not find a PulseAudio daemon running as root... because it is (probably) running as your normal user account if you are logged in, and not running at all if you aren't.

Then, the `xdg-open` will probably try to launcher the system default web browser *as root* with the URL you specified... but because a system service will have no access to any GUI sessions by default, the web browser will fail.

Rather than trying to set up system services to force things into your regular user session, you should set up your timer & service as *user services*, not as *system services*. Basically, instead of placing the unit files into `/etc/systemd/system/`, you should place them into `$HOME/.config/systemd/user/`.
Then logout from the GUI and log back in to test.

When using `systemctl` to operate user services instead of system services, add the `--user` option. So it will be `systemctl --user status youtube.timer` etc.

User services run as the user they belong to, and will automatically have access to the GUI session they're parts of, which should greatly simplify trying to make things happen in your GUI session. The flip side is, if you aren't logged in, those user services won't be running.

Comment: I really appreciate the feedback but I'm still having a hard time understanding how do I find out what X display manager i'm running? Is there a command that can let me know if I am in a GUI session how would I not be I thought using the computer meant i'm always in a GUI session?

Comment: Run `pgrep -a dm$`. It might display one or more processes whose name ends in "dm". Because the pattern is so short, there might be false hits too, but one of them should be something like `/usr/bin/gdm` or `/usr/bin/sddm`. You can use a command like `whatis sddm` to get a one-line description of the potential display manager - if the description includes the words "display manager", you've found it.

Comment: Unix-like systems can also be used in text mode. Some people actually configure their Linuxes to not start the GUI automatically, and login in text console mode. They will then run `startx` if they feel they need the GUI for something. The text console mode can be easier to use than a GUI if you have sight issues, for example. Linux has lots of programs for e.g. email that work just fine in text console mode.

Comment: I ran `pgrep -a dm$` and got `2644 /usr/bin/sddm` then i did `whatis sddm` and got `sddm: nothing appropriate.` what does that even mean exactly ?

Comment: You might not have the manual pages installed or the search index for `whatis` has not been generated. But `/usr/bin/sddm` is the Simple Desktop Display Manager, which is usable with many desktop environments and common with KDE desktops. 2644 is just the Process ID (PID) number of the process. `sddm` starts the X server with a command line like `Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/<filename> ...` and that pathname after `-auth` will vary on each login. That is the file you would need to gain access to the GUI session. `gdm` and other display managers will have different schemes.